# Как пофиксить проблему с hover в меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hover

Когда навожу курсор на элемент меню, появляется выпадающее меню. Когда пытаюсь навести на него, оно пропадает. Как пофиксить?

Comment: Чтобы вам кто нибудь мог помочь - добавьте для начала код вашего выпадающего меню + CSS для него

Comment: да тут даже не в коде дело, просто нужно решение, которое можно js'ом сделать, где-то уже видел, не могу найти.

Comment: Без кода и помощи не окажут, поскольку за Вас искать не будут

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого выпадающее меню должно быть вложено в пункт меню. Все можно реализовать только на css. Пример:

```css
li {cursor: pointer;}
li.submenu ul {display: none; margin: 0px; padding-left: 30px;}
li.submenu:hover ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<li>пункт меню 1</li>
<li>пункт меню 2</li>
<li class="submenu">пункт меню со вложением
  <ul>
    <li>подменю 1</li>
    <li>подменю 2</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>пункт меню 4</li>
```